# Social Club black screens, and I can't play GTA V

Tags: steam, pc, grand-theft-auto-v, rockstar-games-social-club

Recently my copy of GTA V decided to stop working. The launcher goes straight to a black screen after loading for a few minutes. I haven't been able to play since. This is what happens:
[image: Screenshot of the nonworking GTA V launcher]

Specs:

- Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU
- Memory: 12GB
- 64 Bit
- Graphics Card: Nvidia Quadro 2000D

I realize these parts are a million years old, but the game worked before so I'm sure that they are not the problem.
I have the copy on steam

Comment: Have you already tired to reinstall/check consistency?

Comment: Yup I reinstalled the whole game, I also checked cache integrity, reinstalled the social club, cleared %temp%, and restarted my computer several times

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what's causing this issue, but from a few searches on [Rockstar's GTA V forum](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203356618-GTA-5-PC-social-club-blank-screen-error-) I see that there's a pattern to this issue:

> Find and delete/rename the folder called "Rockstar Games" inside of C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\

It seems that deleting the game does not fully clean out this folder. Most of the suggestions to this fix mentions to delete the Rockstar Games folder, but renaming it (Highlight folder and press F2) should fix it as well.  The only problem is that I do not have any information as to what's saved/lost when that folder gets recreated.  Because of this, I highly suggest **renaming the folder and then trying to start the game again**.  In the event there's anything important missing, you can move items from the old "renamed" folder over to the freshly created one to fix.